# Removing countably many points from a manifold

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds

I want to start with the definition of a linear manifold I am using:

A subset $A\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is called $k$-dimensional $\mathcal{C}^\alpha$-submanifold ($\alpha \ge 1$) if for every point $a\in M$ there is an open neighbourhood $U\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and $n-k$ functions $f_j\in\mathcal{C}^\alpha\colon U\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that

$M\cap U=\{x\in U \colon f_1(x)=...=f_{n-k}(x)=0\}\\
\text{rank}\frac{\partial (f_1,...,f_{n-k})}{\partial x_1,...,x_n)}(a)=n-k$

If I remove finitely many points from $M$, I can show that $M$ is still a submanifold, even having the same defining functions as above which are then restricted. (If a point $p$ is removed, and $p\in U$, just pick another (smaller) neighbourhood not cointaining $p$)

So removing finitely many points should not be a problem.

If I were to remove countably infinite points, I can not do the same and there I am not sure if it is still a manifold.

Comment: I'm not really sure what your question is and I'm not great on manifolds, but have you considered $\mathbb{R}^k \setminus \mathbb{Q}^k \subset \mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: Yes, this would exactly be the example I would use. It would not be possible to find functions for this set, right?

Comment: No because $\mathbb{Q}^k$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}^k$ so you can never find a neighbourhood not containing a missing point. Note however that there are examples where this is true, say $\mathbb{R}$ \ $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: On the other hand you can remove $\mathbb{Z}^k$ from $\mathbb{R}^k$ and the result is still a manifold. So all goes fine as long as the points are all decently separated from each other, which is always the case if there are finitely many points.